# Bash (Mac) - Moving Randomized Files to a Multiple Other Folders with a "Fill Limit"

Tags: bash, shell, mv

I have a couple of hundred files in one folder, and I'd like to randomly move them to a number of different folders with a bash script - however, I'd like to fill each of those destination folders only up to a given capacity.

I'm thinking the right way to approach this is to assign two arrays, one containing all destination folders and one containing all files. Then I can randomly take a file from the `filesarr` and place it in a destination folder. My question is, **how can I limit the number of files placed in each destination folder**? So say I'm looking for ten files per destination folder - how can I move the first ten files from `filesarr` to the first folder in `foldersarr`, then move the next ten to the second folder in `foldersarr`, until all files have been moved? I know I should probably use a counter here, but my current attempt (below) is not doing the trick.

```
filesarr=(/Path/to/files/*)  # this is the array of files to shuffle
foldersarr=(/Path/to/destination/folders/) # array of folders to move into

foldercount=0 # set it to 0

for afolder in "${foldersarr[@]}"; do  

  if [[ "$foldercount" -gt 10 ]]; then
       echo "$foldercount files in folder, exiting and moving to next folder"
       exit 1
  else

    for afile in "${filesarr[@]}"; do  # do loop length(array) times; once for each file

        length=${#filesarr[@]}
        randomi=$(( $RANDOM % $length ))  # select a random index

        filename=${filesarr[$randomi]}

        mv ${filename} ${foldersarr[@]}

        echo "moving '$filename'"

        foldercount=$((foldercount+1))
        unset -v "filesarr[$randomi]"  # unset after moved
        array=("${filesarr[@]}")  # remove NULL elements introduced by unset; copy array

    done

  fi

done
```

My current directory structure consists of all the files in a "holding" directory, and all the destination folders where I'd like to move them in a separate folder.

```
rootfolder
│
├── holding
│   ├── dywd.pdf
│   ├── ... (approx. 200 files)
│   └── kjfwekfjnwe.pdf
│   
└── destinations
    ├── folder01
    ├── ...
    └── folder10
```

I'd like to end up with this:

```
rootfolder
│
├── holding
│   
└── destinations
    ├── folder01
    │   ├── lwkejdwe.pdf
    │   ├── ...
    │   └── (ten files in this folder)
    ├── ...
    │
    └── folderXX
        ├── qwuoe.pdf
        ├── ...
        └── (ten files in this folder)
```

Comment: what if you have more files than 10 per destination directory?  Do you want to distribute the files as equally as possible to the dirs or at most ten and leave the rest of the files?

Comment: Good question - I think evenly distributing the files makes the most sense. Although I know in this particular case I have enough destination folders for 10 files per, that may not always be the case.

Answer (score 1):

something like this, (not tested)

```
dirs=(..)  # array of dirs
dir_length=${#dirs[@]}

find -maxdepth 1 -type f |    # or any other list of files
shuf | 
while c=0 IFS= -r file; 
do mv "$file" "{dirs[c++%$dir_length]}"; 
done
```

this will round robin moving files to target directories.  The randomness is generated with `shuf`, no need to maintain the list of files separately.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm still a little new to bash; is it possible for me to use the `filesarr` as above with this? E.g. `filesarr | shuf | c=0;`

Comment: perhaps with `printf '%s\n' "${filesarr[@]}" | shuf ...`

Comment: You're piping to the command `c=0`, and the `while` loop afterwards has no input.

Comment: I installed `coreutils` (I'm on Mac) so I've got `gshuf` now, but I'm still getting command not found on `-r` ... any idea how I could fix that?

Comment: you can remove `-r` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some "buckets" variables and fill each one with the same amount of file names, eg divide all your files in scope into these buckets. Then when done, write each bucket into a separate folder